# How do i start apps like cloudcmd and cordova with forever in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

with forever i could start my website running the command:

```
forever start index.js
```

But i would like to know how could i start apps like cloudcmd and cordova. So I Installed the forever-monitor on ther site root, and was trying to run this command:

```
forever start cloudcmd
```

but i get some error message:
cannot start forever

script /path/to/site/cloudcmd does not exist
Same with cordova:

```
forever start cordova serve
```

cannot start forever

script /path/to/site/cordova does not exist

what am i doing wrong, how could i set this services to be running with forever?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on way of installing node.js applications:

- if you install application globally with **npm i cloudcmd -g** you should determine where main application file of **cloudcmd** located. On UNIX use **which cloudcmd** command. Path will be similar to: **/usr/local/bin/cloudcmd**, to start it with `forever` use: `forever start /usr/local/bin/cloudcmd`
- if you install application locally:
  `git clone https://github.com/coderaiser/cloudcmd cd cloudcmd forever start bin/cloudcmd.js`
  or
  `npm i cloudcmd cd node_modules/cloudcmd forever start bin/cloudcmd.js`

The same with **cordova**.